# Creating a field that calls a method

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception, field, instance-variables

Hi I asked a question a few days back about a Jbutton and a method it's calling. I got an answer about putting the method into a field, so i tried this but I'm met with a null pointer.

```
private Monsters temp = core.anyMonster();
```

The method's origin comes from another class with an arrayList of 'monsters' shown below.

```
public Monsters anyMonster() {
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(monsters.size());
        Monsters monsters1 = monsters.get(index);
        DisplayPanel.changeText("A monster appears! It's a " + monsters1 + "!\n What shall you do?\n");
        return monsters1;
    }
```

It searchs the arrayList and selects a random monster, the method works nicely but the problem was with it repeatedly selecting a new monster rather than just one, so I was told to make it into a field and this would solve the issue.

Then when I actually want to use I call it as so:

```
temp.cleave();
```

Temp is the randomly selected monster with a string name and an int for health. Cleave deducts from these, like a player attack. 
I imagine the problem is how I'm trying to make a method into a field, as the program will crash instantly and will direct me with that line. I'm still a newbie to java so if you could give me some sort of example or help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah nevermind, i surrounded it with some if, else ifs, then added a click counter and i worked it out!